# What is the correct specifier for char, double and float?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int i;
    long int l;
    long long int ll;
    char a;
    float F;
    double D;
    scanf("%i%li%lli%c%f%lf",&i,&l,&ll,&a,&F,&D);
    printf("%i\n%li\n%lli\n%c\n%f\n%lf\n",i,l,ll,a,F,D);
    return 0;
}
```

When I tried to print the value of a,F and D in the above program, it is printing 'h' for 'char' and 0.000000 and 0.000000 for float and double every time .

```
input: 3
       444
       12345678912345
       a
       334.23
       14049.30493
output:3
       444
       12345678912345


       0.000000
       -0.000000
```

Comment: And what is your *input*? And remember that `"%c"` is for printing *characters*, not small integers. See e.g. [this `printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) for more information.

Comment: input: 3
444
12345678912345
a
334.23
14049.30493; output: 3
444
12345678912345
 h
0.000000
0.000000

Comment: By the way, you might want to read [this `scanf` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) as well, as there is no `"%h"` format code, or a `c` modifier. Do you mean `"%hc"`? Then that's not valid either.

Comment: I edited the code and got the above mentioned output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### printf

There's no way to pass a `char` or a `float` to `printf`. They'll be promoted to `int` and `double` respectively in the processing of being passed.

When you pass a `double`, you can use `%f` or `%lf` (the latter was added in C99 though, so some older compilers don't support it).

If you want your `int` printed as a character, you can use the `%c` conversion. If you want it printed as a number, you can use the `%d` or `%i` conversion.

#### scanf

For `scanf` you don't want to pass any of the above--you want to pass a *pointer* to a (char | float | double).

As for the conversion to use, for a pointer to `char` you can use either `%c` or `%s`.

1. `%s` reads a "word"--it skips white-space characters, then reads a group of non-white-space characters.
2. `%c` does more like "raw" reading--for example, if you specify `%15c` it reads the next 15 characters, regardless of whether they're white-space or not.

With both `%c` and `%s`, you *always* want to pass a with (like `%15s` instead of just `%s`) to assure that the user can't enter too much data and overflow the buffer you've provide. `scanf("%s", whatever);` is pretty much equivalent to using `gets`.

With `scanf`, you pass `%f` to read a `float` and `%lf` to read a `double`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`%c`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) for `char` .

Note - You should check return of `scanf` .

[Demo](https://ideone.com/LKeFxv)

Answer (score 0):

When you read  your input, the character you read is the *white-space* between `12345678912345` and `a`. That means that the next format, the floating point, will try to read the letter `a` as a floating pointer value which will not work, and the `scanf` function will return without being able to correctly read and parse all input, leading to your output not matching the input. Many standard and system function returns a value saying if it succeeded or failed, the same with the `scanf` function, and if it doesn't fail completely it will return the number of successfully scanned and parsed items, which would be less than expected in your case.

The `scanf` reference in one of my comments will tell you that most formats skip leading white-space, but `"%c"` does not. If you want to skip leading space before attempting to parse a character, you need to tell `scanf` to do that, by inserting an actual space in the format string, like this:

```
scanf("%i%li%lli %c%f%lf",&i,&l,&ll,&a,&F,&D);
//              ^
// Notice space here
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But I'm getting extra zero( '0') at the end of the output of Double, which is '14049.304930' instead of '14049.30493'.